# About line passing through points inside the region bounded by a closed curve in the plane

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given a closed curve on the $x-y$ plane, is it possible that given any point $A$ inside the region bounded by the closed curve, there is a straight line passing through $A$ such that the intersected points of the line with the closed curve are at equal distance from the point $A$.

I just thought about this question.

Comment: Hint Consider any initial line through $A$ and consider the a function of the difference between the distance from one point on the curve to $A$ and from $A$ to the other point. Now, if these distances are not equal, consider what happens to the values of the function as the points move around the closed curve until they switch places.

Comment: My hint above assumes that if the straight line through $A$ intersects the closed curve in more than one place on one side of $A$, you can choose which point you wish to consider for checking equal distance. However, if you always use the points closest to $A$, then it's not immediately clear to me whether or not there will always be such a straight line with equal distances. I suggest you update your question text to explicitly state how you want to have multiple curve intersections on one side of $A$ be handled. Thanks.

Comment: It is fine! as long as there is two points on the line intersection with the closed curve at equidistance to the point $A$ is all that is needed!

Comment: Thanks for responding. Since my hint should work to show what you're asking, did the hint make sense to you? If you wish, I can write up answer explaining it in a bit more detail.

Comment: Sorry Ok, if the closed curve is not convex, then it is possible for the line to intersect in more than two points on the curve. In that case, the function could have potentially many images for a given line. Also, even if we choose the furthest intersecting points away from the point $A$ as the  domain of the function, It not guarantee that the function is continuous? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Regardless whether or not it's convex, a closed curve contains a continuous line that starts & ends at the same point. As long as the end points of the line through $A$ move along this continuous line, the function of the difference in distances would be continuous, including up to when the points switch positions. Note for non-convex closed curves, these points may at various times be, or not be, the furthest intersections points away from $A$. If you require the points to always be the furthest, then as I stated earlier, I'm not sure you can guarantee equal distances will occur.